# Extension not found. Cogs discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code.

```
for filename in os.listdir('lib\commands'):
if filename.endswith('.py'):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

My error:

```
Exception has occurred: ExtensionNotFound
Extension 'cogs.ping_clear' could not be loaded.
  File "C:\Users\sakch\Desktop\Bot\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

[This is my folder where the file is present.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0sy7.png)

Comment: Plase, provide a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting the wrong path in `load_extension`. You should pass the same path as in `os.listdir`

```py
for filename in os.listdir('lib\commands'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'lib.commands.{filename[:-3]}')
```